# Decrementar os formulários JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um código quando a pessoa clica em add o codigo gera outros formularios.. mas como faço pra em cada formulario ter a opção de excluir? Obs: Não quero excluir o ultimo adicionado e sim um determinado.

```js
var counter = 1;
jQuery('a.add-author').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name' +
        counter + '"/></td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="authors-list">
  <tr><td>author's first name</td><td>author's last name</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name" /></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name" /></td></tr>
</table>
<a href="#" title="" class="add-author">Add Author</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De um id para as td adicionada e remova usando essa identificação
exemplo abaixo:

```js
var counter = 1;
jQuery('a.add-author').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr id="author-'+counter+'"><td><input type="text" name="first_name' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name' +
        counter + '"/></td><td onclick="remove('+counter+')">x</td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
});

function remove(a){
  $('#author-'+a).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="authors-list">
  <tr><td>author's first name</td><td>author's last name</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name" /></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name" /></td></tr>
</table>
<a href="#" title="" class="add-author">Add Author</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize uma outra coluna com um botão e no evento `onClick` desse botão, você adiciona `$(this).parents('tr').remove();`

Ex:

```js
var counter = 1;
jQuery('a.add-author').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><button type="button" onClick="$(this).parents(\'tr\').remove()">Remover</button></td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="authors-list">
  <tr>
    <td>author's first name</td>
    <td>author's last name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="first_name" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="last_name" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a href="#" title="" class="add-author">Add Author</a>
```

Ou ainda você adicionar `<button class="remove" type="button">Remover</button>` e no `Js` adicionar:

```
$(".remove").click(functions() {
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
});
```

Comment: E para desabilitar o botão remover no primeiro item? No caso aparecer o remover somente a partir do segundo?

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function($) {

RemoveTableRow = function(handler) {
var tr = $(handler).closest('tr');

tr.fadeOut(400, function(){ 
  tr.remove(); 
}); 

return false;
  }; 

var counter = 1;
jQuery('a.add-author').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name' + counter + '"/>' +
    '</td><td><input type="text" name="last_name' +counter + '"/></td>' +
    '<td class="actions"><button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button></td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
});

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <table class="authors-list">
   <tr><td>author's first name</td><td>author's last name</td></tr>
   <tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name" /></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name" /></td></tr>
 </table>
 <a href="#" title="" class="add-author">Add Author</a>
```

> na última coluna colocamos o botão de remover a linha.

```
<td class="actions"><button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button></td>
```